# Fatal Error cannot use 'Bool' in Lexer.php

Tags: php-errors, error-500

We recently migrated one of our websites using EE to a new server running php7. We're getting the following error:

**Fatal error:** Cannot use EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Parser\Conditional\Token\Bool as Bool because 'Bool' is a special class name in /home/.../public_html/system/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Parser/Conditional/Lexer.php on line 9

Here is line 9 from Lexer.php :

```
use EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Parser\Conditional\Token\Bool;
```

I tried setting 'allow_extensions' to 'n' and nothing changed. Also, I am able to log into the back-end.

Running EE version 2.10.2

It seems that using 'Bool' is no longer supported in php7. Does anyone know of a solution? Is there a fix for this in EE3?

Thanks.

Comment: Tell us what version of EE you're using too pls.

Comment: Running ver 2.10.2

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that may come across this error in the future, we were able to resolve it by changing all instances of 'Bool' and 'String' that were inside the system>EllisLab folder to 'Boolean' and 'StringLiteral' respectively. Bool and String are reserved terms in PHP 7 and their usage in these 4 files (Lexer.php, Parser.php, Bool.php, String.php) was causing errors, so changing them to the updated terms resolved it.

We were using a bit of an older version of EE (2.10.2). I believe these terms are updated in the latest versions though.

Comment: It help.. thanks.. but i still got many php errors as 
Message: Object of class EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Parser\Conditional\Token\Variable could not be converted to string